# What is the shortcut for commenting out multiple lines at one time in Jenkins file?

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

What is the shortcut for commenting out multiple lines at one time in Jenkins file? (edit in IntelliJ)? I tried 'ctrl + /' because it works for Java, but for some reason it didn't work for Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Could you expand on *"didn't work"*? The Jenkinsfile is Groovy, which does have comment syntax http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_comments, so if the file association is correct I'd expect that shortcut to work. Do you see syntax highlighting?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe I know how to comment out, I just wanted to know the short cut for commenting out multiple lines in Jenkins file

Comment: Did you mark your jeninsfile as 'groovy' file? (<- Right-click on file in project tree, second entry from top: "Associate with File Type ...")

Comment: @SaschaKolberg yes, it's a groovy file, should I choose 'java' in this "Associate with File Type"? and the shortcut works after this, but will it affect my Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting multiple lines and `cmd + /` does it

Comment: I'm not using Mac, I tried 'ctrl+/', 'shift+/','alt+/' but all don't work

Comment: you should use 'windows + /' if you are using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Select a stage and press `ctrl` + `/`

Answer (score 0):

You have to associate the file with a File Type. Otherwise it is only text to IDEA.

Right click the file in the Project Browser and chose

- "Associate with File Type..." and in "Open matching files in IntelliJ IDEA" choose "Groovy"
  or
- "Override File Type" and choose "Groovy" if it already has a File Type associated.

After that, `ctrl` + `/` should work.